# Group headings lost when a filter is applied

Tags: sharepoint-online, grouping, sharepoint-list-filter

I have an interesting bug occurring - only to a select number of people (so not everyone has this issue.) I have a customized view display, grouped by a given field. Some of my users will open the filter panel and apply a filter. When they do - the list redisplays with no group headers. All data cards display one after another.

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue seemed to be tied to a configuration setting on the list for Mobile devices. By disabling the list display for Mobile, all the filtering issues were resolved. I do not have a good answer as to WHY this fixes it. But - every since disabling the setting, we've had no issues.

Answer (score 0):

The following are my test steps, without the problem described in your original post.

1.Create two columns: client name and representative name，use them concatenated as a calculated field client client_and_rep.
[image]

2.Group by client_and_rep column.
[image]

3.Filter by Client Name column, group headers still exist.
[image]

Update:

## [image]

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The answer to your question is ... sorta.   LOL 

We have two columns: client name and representative name. I use them concatenated as a calculated field client client_and_rep.  This field is used as the grouping so that I can put the Client and Rep name on the heading.  However - the actual filter is applied to the Client Name field - not the combined field.

But once again ---- this is only happening for a FEW people. For most - the past has no issue.  

Also - if the afflicted user adds "&groupby=ClientName" to the end of the "bad" page view, it corrects itself.

Comment: I want to confirm with you that what does "the affected user adds "&groupby=ClientName" to the end of the "bad" page view, it corrects itself how it is doing mean"? Could you provide some explanation and screenshots?

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check.

Comment: Emily  - when the user gets the "bad" experience after applying a filter, I have learned that the URL is missing the groupBy clause. Manually adjusting the URL with "groupBy=ClientName" fixes the issue. The user can then bookmark the URL and has a means to get what s/he needs. However, this is only a temporary fix as the filter needs will change, and will have to go through these steps again to save a new/fresh bookmark.

Comment: Client_and_rep is used as a grouping and the filter is applied to the client name field. Please check my url. It is recommended that you try a different list to see if this will solve the problem.

Comment: Emily - this is exactly what we're doing. Two independent fields for client and rep are combined in a calculated field client_and_rep. The grouping is on client_and_rep.  The filter is on client. 

I cannot stress this enough...   it is only happening to a handful of people.  MOST of my staff have no issue with the display and filtering.  THAT'S the confusing part!!!  It happened to my manager once. Then she 'refreshed' and it's never happened to her, since.  Same with me. It never happened while developing. When brought to my attention - it happened once.  After a refresh ... never again.

Comment: I suggest you open a service request with Microsoft.